# EXCEL: Column A input to Column B output

Tags: excel, python-3.x, excel-formula

I have never really used Excel, but I am decent at Python 3 (so I can follow computer logic somewhat).

I use Excel a lot for work, and I waste a lot of time repeating the same values.
What I am trying to do is have Excel auto-fill rows if columns match.

For example, imagine each color of the rainbow (column A) corresponds to a different user (column B) and number (column C).

```
    Red     =>   Steve    => 1
    Orange  =>   Jeremy   => 2
    Yellow  =>   Sarah    => 3
    etc.
```

How do I make these outputs automatic so that if I input in A12:

```
    Orange  =>  ......    => ......
```

It auto-fills B12 and C12 as:

```
    Orange  =>   Jeremy  => 2
```

In a META sense, I want Excel to retroactively see which values in Column A match, and auto-fill the other columns.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You can use `VLOOKUP()` for this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response! 
What's the format for VLOOKUP() ?

Comment: What is Google?  (Am I doing this right?)  I'm not trying to be flip, but this is a pretty basic Excel formula for which there are tons of resources already available.  There's no benefit in me copy-pasting one of those here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Williams said, you can use VLOOKUP() formula.
Put this formula in B12 :

```
=VLOOKUP(A7;$A$1:$C$3;2;0)
```

And this in C12 :

```
=VLOOKUP(A7;$A$1:$C$3;3;0)
```

Sheet sample :

[image: Sheet sample]